# Multithreading and keeping a stable communication with GUI with JavaFx

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I'm trying to create a method that reads words from a file and display them on a JavaFx label . I'm doing this by using a Service and Task for the background work , while using the Platform.runLater() to communicate with the GUI . The problem is that the work is actually done , but it shows only the last word coming from the file . Here is the code :

```
@FXML
private void launchLecture() {
     if (stateFile)
     mainApp.textTreatment();
    System.out.println("Done");
    if ((new File(mainApp.getLinkToPdf()).exists())) {
        File fl = new File(mainApp.getLinkToPdf());

        Service<Void> service = new Service<Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Task<Void> createTask() {

                return new Task<Void>() {

                    @Override
                    protected Void call() throws Exception {
                        Scanner sc = new Scanner(fl);
                        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
                        Platform.runLater(() -> {
                            try {
                                int count = 3;
                                while (count >= 0) {
                                    wordToShow.setText(count + "...");
                                    try {
                                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    count--;
                                }
                                // ---
                                while (sc.hasNext()) {
                                             wordToShow.setText(sc.next().toString());
                                    try {
                                        Thread.sleep(speed);
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } finally{
                                latch.countDown();
                            }

                        });
                        latch.await();
                        return null;
                    }
                };
            }
        };
        service.start();

    }

}
```

I tried many of the solutions I found on StackOverFlow but still can't get the problem fixed .

Comment: Yes , I think one of the problem is coming from the sleep() , any idea on how i can only put to sleep only the background thread ?And yes , the idea is to replace the previous word.

Comment: Yes. Don't put the while loop in the `runLater`. In fact, the only thing that should be in `runLater` is the actual GUI code (`setText`). Keep the while loop and other computational logic on the normal thread, then use `runLater` to forward your `setText` calls to the GUI thread.

Comment: Why are you wrapping the entire loop with `Platform.runLater(...)`? Just wrap the calls to `setText(...)` with `Platform.runLater(...)`.

Comment: I misunderstood the use of the Platform.runLater() , that's why I was putting the whole loop and sleeping the thread inside it . My issue is fixed , thank you !